# Go to last non-whitespace character of previous/next line?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

I like the `-` and `<C-M>` normal-mode keys for going to the first non-whitespace character of the previous/next line.

Are there coresponding keys for going to the *last* non-whitespace character on the previous/next line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`g_` moves the cursor to the last non-blank character of the *current* line. From Vim's [`:help g_`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#g_):

```
g_          To the last non-blank character of the line and
            [count - 1] lines downward |inclusive|. {not in Vi}
```

Unfortunately, I think the only options you have to move to the non-blank character of the previous/next line is `kg_` or `jg_` respectively or using a count to move downwards.

However, it is easy to map them to something easier:

```
nnoremap <F3> kg_
nnoremap <F4> jg_
```

Comment: Also note that `2g_` will also work if you want to go to the last non whitespace character on the next line.  However, this can't be used for the previous line.  The advantage of `2g_` is that it can be repeated with `.`

Comment: Motions (like `g_`) are not repeatable with `.`. Generally, only things that change the state of the buffer can be repeated.

Comment: Though, when combined with an operator, repeating works. Perhaps that's what you were referring to

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize motions weren't repeatable.  I should look at the docs before I say things.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the next non-whitespace character of the previous/next lines (by going vertically), then try:

```
map <C-k> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'bW')<CR>
map <C-j> :call search('\%' . virtcol('.') . 'v\S', 'wW')<CR>
```