# Paste at cursor instead of below

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-movement

If I start with this file:

```
https://example.com
<>
```

and press `ddp`, I expect to get this:

```
<https://example.com>
```

but instead I get this:

```
<>
https://example.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dd` performs a __linewise__ operation. To paste within the current line, the delete operator needs to be a given a __characterwise__ motion. More details [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6946/21495)

Comment: To accomplish that in three keystrokes: `DJp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, can use:

<kbd>D</kbd>

Or:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>

https://fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html

Answer (score 1):

Like husB commented you have to use a characterwise motion.
Note that `D` deletes from the current cursor position to the end of the line and doesn't delete the line itself.

You could overwrite what `dd` does but I would recommend you map your expected behaviour to a new command, `<leader>d` in the following mapping:

```
:nmap <leader>d 0D"_dd
```

The command does the following:

- `0`: go to the beginning of the line

  - `0` includes whitespace, use `^` or `_` instead to go to the first non-blank character
- `D`: cut characterwise to the end of the line

  - also includes whitespace, can be replaced by `dg_` to cut to the last non-blank character instead, see [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/go-to-last-non-whitespace-character-of-previous-next-line)
- `"_` is the "black hole register" to keep your default register (used by `p`) clean
- `dd`: cuts the now empty line into `"_`